# Group by a certain criteria - SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I need to group my customers using a criteria specified in a column but using multiple rows as condition. As an example:

| CustomerID | Status | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | Rejected | June |
| Customer2 | Accepted | June |
| Customer2 | Rejected | June |
| Customer3 | Rejected | June |
| Customer4 | Accepted | June |

In this case, I would like to group by month and count the amount of distinct customers that were only rejected, the amount that were only accepted and the amount that where both rejected and accepted- Therefore, the expected outcome would be:

| Month | accepted & rejected | rejected | accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| June | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Check if this suits your needs:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerStatus
(
CustomerID  INT, 
Status VARCHAR(20),
Month VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO CustomerStatus(CustomerID, Status, Month) VALUES
(1, 'Rejected', 'June'),
(2, 'Accepted', 'June'),
(2, 'Rejected', 'June'),
(3, 'Rejected', 'June'),
(4, 'Accepted', 'June')

SELECT CustomerStatus.[Month], 
       SUM(CASE 
                WHEN accepted is NOT null AND rejected is NOT null THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) [Accepted & Rejected],

       SUM(CASE 
                WHEN rejected is NOT null AND accepted is NULL THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) [Rejected],

        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN accepted is NOT null AND rejected is NULL THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) [Accepted]             
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
       CustomerStatus.[Month],  
       accepted.CustomerID accepted,
       rejected.CustomerID rejected
FROM CustomerStatus
LEFT JOIN CustomerStatus accepted ON CustomerStatus.CustomerID = accepted.CustomerID AND accepted.Status = 'Accepted'
LEFT JOIN CustomerStatus rejected ON CustomerStatus.CustomerID = rejected.CustomerID AND rejected.Status = 'Rejected') CustomerStatus
GROUP BY [Month]
```

If you find my answer useful, I would appreciate if you mark as accepted and vote up.